# Email Client in Android using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am tryin to use an email client in my application. I am using plugins for the same.

The code that am using is

```
function tellAFriend()
{

        var succcallback = function(result) {
            //alert("Mail sent");
        };
        var errorcallback = function(e) {
            //alert("error:" + e);
        };
            var body1='Hi,\n I came across this new app and thought you might be interested';
            var body2=body1+'.You can check it out at \n';
            var href1='market';

            var anchortext;
            anchor1 = document.createElement("a");
            anchortext = document.createTextNode('Test');
            anchor1.appendChild(anchortext);
            anchor1.href=href1;
            anchor1.setAttribute('href','https://market.android.com/details?id=com.unisys.cps&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS51bmlzeXMuY3BzIl0');
            //alert(anchor1);

            window.plugins.webintent.tellAFriend({
            mailSubject   : 'CPS Mobile App',
            mailRecepients: '',
            mailBody: href1
            //mailBody: 'Hi,\n I came across this new app and thought you might be interested.You can check it out at \nhttps://market.android.com/details?id=com.unisys.cps&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS51bmlzeXMuY3BzIl0 \nor \nhttps://www.cargoportalservices.com/lmsweb/DownloadCPSMobileApp.jsp'
        }, succcallback, errorcallback);

}
```

Thats the function. In the function, the mail body that i have provided needs to be a text. but I need to pass a hyoerlink to it. Meaning, when the email client opens up, the text should be displayed as hyperlinks.

Any suggestions on how that can be achieved.